# function to print min and max value of an array using c++ pointers

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I'm trying to understand pointers in c++ so I made a function that takes an array and the length of that array and print out the min and max values of that array, however, it always just print the last element in that array for both min and max, I went through my code line by line but I still don't understand the reason for this behavior, can you please help understand and fix my code, thanks.

```
void getMinAndMax(int numbers[], int length)
{
  int *min = &numbers[0];
  int *max = &numbers[0];
  cout << length << endl;
  for (int i = 1; i < length; i++)
  {
    if (*min > numbers[i])
    {
      *min = numbers[i];
    }
    if (*max < numbers[i])
    {
      *max = numbers[i];
    }
  }
  cout << "min: " << *min << endl;
  cout << "max: " << *max << endl;
}
```

Comment: Did you try debugging the code? `*min = numbers[i];` this does not reassign the pointer.

Comment: Use separate local variables for the min and max values.

Comment: Both `min` and `max` point to the same memory `numbers[0]`, so both `*min = numbers[i];` and `*max = numbers[i];` write stuff to _the same memory_, so it makes sense that they point to the same value.

Comment: I don't see this a great exercise for understanding the 'why' of pointers. I suppose it can work for the 'how,' but you don't need pointers when you pass an array, you're just muddying the waters.

Comment: @sweenish It's fine to start with "how".

Comment: Ask yourself what `*min = numbers[i]` means. If you still don't understand, try printing all the pointer values.

Comment: @PasserBy I never said it wasn't, but I also wasn't very clear. When working on 'how' I think it's better to find a problem that actually takes advantage of the new thing you're trying to learn instead of shoehorning your principle into the wrong types of problems. The 'how' and the 'why' can never be fully disconnected from each other, so let's stop trying.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ thanks to your advice I did the following modifications and the function now works, but I still don't understand what exactly happened though :)
  int x = numbers[0];
  int y = numbers[0];
  int *min = &x;
  int *max = &y;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since, you are using the de-referencing operator in the if condition. You are basically changing the value at the memory location where the pointer is pointing (in this case the 0th index of the array). What you should do in the if condition is store the index where the minimum and maximum values are present.
Like so

```
if (*min > numbers[i])
{
min = &numbers[i];
}
```

This way, the pointer will hold the addresses of the maximum and minimum values and when you dereference them, you will get the right answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot that was really helpful ^_^